# Regex check if word is succeeded by certain words

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word, whitespace

I am making a programming language in native C++, with which I am making a basic editor in C#. NET WinForms. However, I am using a `SyntaxRTB`, with which I would like the Regex to catch the following error:

> if declare is not succeeded by string / int / float / bool / array / char

How would I do that?

(The syntax to declare a variable is `declare variable_type variable_name`) - A whitespace would have to be accounted for too)

I have `declare(?!string)`, but am still confused.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a regex, you need a zero-width [negative lookahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But if you're constructing a language, this isn't the way to go. Full-blown language parsers are a different entity.

Comment: I would agree (+1). RegEx to parse source code would be painful (IMHO). A language parser that tokenizes the source is what the OP should be writing.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with @fejesjoco, this is the expression I used [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/):
`(declare)[\s](int|string|float|bool|array|char)[\s](.*)`

[image: image showing declare groups]

Check for `!match(pattern)` to further diagnose an issue.

Comment: +1 if you can tell me how to negate that pattern: to get all the items which don't match the rule

Comment: You will have to be more specific; the expression does not match on the following examples: `declare boo baz`; `declareint foo`; `declare foo int`

Comment: As in the ones that aren't `declare int me` `declare string foo`

Comment: Easy ... `if (!match(pattern)){  ...  }` ... but again, this is better suited to a language parser (tokenizer).

Comment: I have a tokenizer in C++, but I prefer to do my forms in c#

Comment: Share you tokenizer with the .Net layer (P/Invoke or C++/CLI). RegEx is not a good solution for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use Lookahead assertion. To be honest, I'm decent in Regex but I'm not really the guy you want explaining it to you.

[This link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will explain it better than I can, and [this link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) provides a fairly decent Regex editor.